# Error in Power Apps: Expression "XXX eq null" is not supported

Tags: error, powerapp, powerapps-canvas

I get an error in Power Apps when starting the app but it dissappears later.

The error displays:

> Error when trying to retrieve data from the network:
> Expression "homeTeam eq null" is not supported.

In the gallery I have written this in Items:

```
Sort(Filter(MenTeams, StartsWith(teamId, "A")), Sum(Filter(MenGroupMatches,homeTeam=teamId), homePoints) + Sum(Filter(MenGroupMatches, awayTeam=teamId),awayPoints), SortOrder.Descending)
```

The datasource is Excel online (located on Sharepoint).

Any help on how to solve this error would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What is the value of `teamId` when you load screen/gallery?

Comment: The value is based on each team from the list (it can be A1, A2, A3, B1, B2...).

Comment: Where are you setting the teamId variable? I think it is blank/null at some time hence you are receiving this error.

Comment: It's loaded from the same Excel online. There are two tables in that excel one is MenTeams and the other one is MenGroupMatches.